# bash variable replace first letter with the letter in [] using string manipulation

Tags: bash, awk

let's say I have:

```
variable=string
```

and now would like to replace use brackets for the first letter

```
${variable/firstletter/[firstletter]}
```

Finally I want to use it in the script to modify a regex pattern so that it doesn't match itself:

```
ps -e -o time,user,pid,ppid,comm,args | grep ${variable/firstletter/[firstletter]}
```

I'd like to use it instead of additional pipe and `grep -v grep` or `pgrep`

Also, maybe you know how to achieve such process grep with awk and not print awk command itself?

Comment: Are the typos of variable to varaible real or copy:paste?

Comment: Do you have pgrep available?

Comment: _Why_ do you not want to use `pgrep`?

Answer (score 6):

You just need to grab the first character of your parameter, to wrap in brackets, then add the rest back:

```
bash-[508]$ variable=string
bash-[509]$ echo $variable
string
bash-[510]$ echo $variable to [${variable:0:1}]${variable:1}
string to [s]tring
```

So your command might be something like:

```
ps -e -i time,user,pid,ppid,comm,args | grep "[${variable:0:1}]${variable:1}"
```

This is using bash parameter substitution on ranges of characters in a variable, given as where to start, and how long the grab should be.

`${variable:0:1}`, starts at character 0, the start of the string, and grabs 1 character.  Thus isolating the first letter, `v`.

`${variable:1}`, then starts at character 1, and without a defined range, grabs everything up to the end of $variable, grabbing `ariable`.

Answer (score 1):

I have just such a function in my .bashrc, except I can take multiple search patterns:

```
psg () {
    local -a patterns=()
    (( $# == 0 )) && set -- $USER
    for arg in "$@"; do
        patterns+=("-e" "[${arg:0:1}]${arg:1}");
    done
    ps -ef | grep --color=auto "${patterns[@]}"
}
```

and yes, I know `pgrep` exists.

```
$ psg fish bash vim grep
glennj       2     1 67 09:00 ?        02:32:31 fish
glennj     153     1  0 09:00 tty2     00:00:06 fish
glennj    3122     1  0 11:08 tty3     00:00:07 fish
glennj    3964   153  0 12:14 tty2     00:00:00 vim supersecretfile
glennj    4992  3122  0 12:41 tty3     00:00:00 bash
glennj    5162  4992  0 12:45 tty3     00:00:00 grep --color=auto -e [f]ish -e [b]ash -e [v]im -e [g]rep
```

Comment: that's a great idea.  my `.bashrc` will have a very similar function in just a couple of minutes. :D

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
#!/bin/sh 

variable=rsyslogd

regex="[$(expr "$variable" : '\(.\)')]""${variable#?}"
echo "$regex"
ps -e -o time,user,pid,ppid,comm,args | grep '$regex'
```

Testing:

```
$ ./script
[r]syslogd
00:00:00 root       521     1 rsyslogd        /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n
```

This might fail if the first character of variable is special \ [ ] * ?  etc.

Answer (score 0):

> maybe you know how to achieve such process grep with awk and not print awk command itself?

With GNU awk, we could exclude the `awk` process itself by using `PROCINFO`
to get the script's PID.

```
$ pattern=cron
$ ps -e -o time,user,pid,ppid,comm,args  |
  gawk -vpat="$pattern" 'NR == 1 || $3 != PROCINFO["pid"] && $0 ~ pat' 
    TIME USER       PID  PPID COMMAND         COMMAND
00:00:10 root       530     1 cron            /usr/sbin/cron -f
```

Change `$0 ~ pat` to `index($0, pat)` to implement a fixed-string match instead of a regex match.

Though of course, you could use `pgrep` in combination with `ps`:

```
$ ps -o time,user,pid,ppid,comm,args $(pgrep "$pattern")
    TIME USER       PID  PPID COMMAND         COMMAND
00:00:10 root       530     1 cron            /usr/sbin/cron -f
```